# Ionic cordova HTTP plugin header not added when using basic auth

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, basic-authentication, cordova-plugin-advanced-http

Hi im trying to send post request with basic auth in Cordova Ionic Framework v6, but the console log response if im not adding it. Here is screenshot from console log when i added basic auth:

Console log when use basic auth:

[image]

Im following tutorial from ionic documentation [ionic documentaion http](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http) and the github one [cordova-plugin-advanced-http](https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http).

but when i didnt use basic auth the header added, i tried with some code like:

```
this.http.useBasicAuth('user', 'password');
```

adding directly to header param :

```
this.http.post('someURL', {"username" :username, "password" :password}, {'Authorization': 'Basic ZHJlYW1fMS4wOmRyZWFtXzEuMA==', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
```

but the response always like the image 1 the header not added. Any solution for this porblem ?, or maybe I am missing something ?.

Heres my code :

```
import { HTTP } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/http/ngx';

constructor(private http: HTTP) {}

call(){
this.http.post('url', {"username" :variable username, "password" : variable password}, { 'Authorization': 'Basic ZHJlYW1fMS4wOmRyZWFtXzEuMA==', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
  .then(res=> {

    console.log(res);

  })
  .catch(err=> {

    console.log(err);

  });
}
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: i'm sorry look like i made a mistake, the code in above is working, but i test it on browser not device. seems like the code will run in device only. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Running browser in insecure mode allows the ionic native http to work in the browser**.
run 
`google-chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="~/insecure_data_blabla"` (Linux)
And open your development server in it.